# What is the name of this instrument?

Tags: instruments, woodwinds

While watching [this exceptional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DT1NJwEi6nw), I noticed the instrument used to do the whistling at 0:33. It looks like a long **ocarina**, but I wonder what the exact name of this instrument is (I am also intrigued, although more trivially, by the "wind" machine at the beginning).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because identification questions are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an Alto Ocarina, very much like [this one](https://www.thomann.de/gb/thomann_10_loch_konzertocarina_c3.htm?sid=afb258877f65dfcb8d0b253ebd0f080d).